# Relation one to many with findOne returned only single relation record

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have two model:

1. PostingTask
2. PostingFlowQueue

They look like this

**PostingTask:**

```
import pkg from 'sequelize'
import connection from '../db/connection.js'
import jobStatus from '../common/jobStatus.js'

const {Model, DataTypes} = pkg

export default class PostingTask extends Model { }

PostingTask.init({
    ID: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    PostingID: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    Status: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: jobStatus.awaiting
    },
    FromState: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    ToState: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    createdAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        field: 'CreatedAt'
    },
    updatedAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        field: 'UpdatedAt'
    },
}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    sequelize: connection.sequelize,
    modelName: 'PostingTask'
})
```

**PostingFlowQueue:**

```
import pkg from 'sequelize'

const {Model, DataTypes} = pkg
import connection from '../db/connection.js'
import jobStatus from '../common/jobStatus.js'

export default class PostingFlowQueue extends Model { }

PostingFlowQueue.init({
   ID: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    PostingTaskID: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    Status: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: jobStatus.awaiting
    },
    ToState: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    ByChange: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    TargetPath: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    DataForChange: DataTypes.STRING,
    ErrorMessage: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        field: 'CreatedAt'
    },
    updatedAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        field: 'UpdatedAt'
    },
}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    sequelize: connection.sequelize,
    modelName: 'PostingFlowQueue'
})
```

Relation for this models
**index.js**

```
import PostingTask from './postingtask.mjs'
import PostingFlowQueue from './postingflowqueue.mjs'

PostingTask.hasMany(PostingFlowQueue, {
    foreignKey: 'PostingTaskID', as: 'Queue'
});

PostingFlowQueue.belongsTo(PostingTask, {
    foreignKey: 'ID'
})

export {PostingTask, PostingFlowQueue}
```

*Problem I'm trying to solve:*

I need to get all relation records from PostingTask

*How i try to do it:*

```
import {PostingFlowQueue, PostingTask} from '../models/index.mjs'
import jobStatus from '../common/jobStatus.js'

async function init() {
    await PostingTask.findOne({
        where: {Status: jobStatus.awaiting},
        include: [{all: true, attributes: ['ByChange']}]
    }).then(task => {
        console.log(task.Queue)
    })
}

init()
```

*Problem:*
Only one relation record is returned

Please tell me where i could wrong.

I really tried a lot of things, but I could not understand my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Your primary and foreign keys seem off.
Shouldn't ID be the primary key for PostingFlowQueue?
The foreign key for a relationship always refers to the same field.
So it should be

```
PostingTask.hasMany(PostingFlowQueue, {
    foreignKey: 'PostingTaskID', as: 'Queue'
});

PostingFlowQueue.belongsTo(PostingTask, {
    foreignKey: 'PostingTaskID'
})
```

Have you tried the same query with findAll or looked at the generated query?

Comment: Yes i'm try it, result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I find solution! Quite strange but still...

```
async function init() {
        await PostingTask.findOne({
            where: {Status: jobStatus.awaiting},
            include: [{
                model: postingflowqueue,
                attributes:['ID', 'Status']
            }],
        }).then(task => {
            //task.update({Status: jobStatus.processing})
    
            task.getPostingFlowQueues().then(async steps => {
                console.log(step)
            })
        })
    }
```